# map tag in responsive image doesn't work- update

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm starting with map with bootstrap 3 and I want to use a map area to make two links in a image, im using the following:

```
<img src="img/bannerQhapacNanCompleto.jpg" alt="menu" class="img-responsive" usemap="#inscripciones" width="1280"  height="905">
<map name="inscripciones">
  <area shape="rect"  coords="77,415,590,891" alt="produccion" href="http://www.google.com">
</map>
```

it works perfectly when I used a PC, but in a mobile device the map doesn't work, please help me.
-UPDATE--
I use this code to try but i can't  work on resize could helpe me with that please.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var ancho=$('#imagen').width(); 
var alto=$('#imagen').height();
var mediaX=ancho/2;var mediaY=alto/2;
var cuartoX=mediaX/2;
var cuartoY=mediaY/2; 
var x1=0;var y1=mediaY-cuartoY;
var coordenadas1="0,"+alto+","+mediaX+","+mediaY;
var coordenadas2=mediaX+","+mediaY+","+ancho+","+alto;
$('#produccion').attr( "coords", coordenadas1 );
$('#libroObjeto').attr( "coords", coordenadas2 );
});
```

Comment: You will probably need to use a script to adjust the `coords` of the map to ensure it's aligned with the image when it's resized on the client.

Comment: Could you help me with the resize event please ?

Comment: You're probably better-off using an absolutely-positioned `<a>` instead of a `<map>` as it will scale and because you're using rectangular areas. I think `<map>` is dead anyway.

Comment: Dear friends,made this to make work the map: ` $( document ).ready(function() {var ancho=$('#imagen').width();                    var alto=$('#imagen').height();var mediaX=ancho/2;var mediaY=alto/2;
                    var cuartoX=mediaX/2;var cuartoY=mediaY/2;
                    var x1=0;var y1=mediaY-cuartoY;
                    var coordenadas1="0,"+alto+","+mediaX+","+mediaY; var coordenadas2=mediaX+","+mediaY+","+ancho+","+alto; 
$('#produccion').attr( "coords", coordenadas1 );
$('#libroObjeto').attr( "coords", coordenadas2 );`  but  can't find the event when i make a resize

Comment: you should put that code in a update of your question. its a pain to read it within a comment ;)